# Destructor causes corruption of the heap.

Tags: c++, destructor

I'm playing around with destructors and I don't understand why I get an error for this code when the `main` function terminates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

class RGBA {
    uint8_t _red, _blue, _green, _alpha;
    int *_arr;
    int _length;
public:
    RGBA(int *arr, int length, uint8_t r = 0, uint8_t b = 0, uint8_t g = 0, uint8_t a = 255): 
      _red (r), _blue (b), _green (g), _alpha (a) {
      _arr = arr;
      _length = length;
      }
      ~RGBA() {
          cout << "Destroying object" << endl;
          delete[] _arr;
      }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < _length; ++i) {
            cout << _arr[i] << endl;
        }
        cout << static_cast<int>(_red) << " " << static_cast<int>(_blue) << " " << static_cast<int>(_green) << " " << static_cast<int>(_alpha) << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
    RGBA rgba(arr, 3);
    rgba.print();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs, but then when I press Enter, it prints 'Destroying object' with the following error "This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in testcpp.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.".

```
1
2
3
0 0 0 255
```

I use VS2010 on Win7.

Comment: `delete[]` needs a pointer to an object allocated with `new[]`. You never allocate anything with `new[]` in your example.

Comment: The destructor doesn't cause your problem. Supplying a pointer to a statically allocated, and thus not-`delete`able array to the constructor is.

Answer (score 6):

The automatic storage duration variable `int arr[3]` will be automatically deallocated when the enclosing function exits.

Trying to `delete[]` it causes undefined behavior. Only objects allocated with `new[]` can be deallocated with `delete[]`.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, this is effectively what is happening:

```
int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
delete[] arr;
```

Your `arr` in `main` is in automatic storage. You pass it into your object, which assumes ownership and assumes the memory was dynamically allocated with `new`.

You should only `delete []` what you `new []`.

Answer (score 1):

The array you are passing, `arr` is being allocated on the stack in your main function. You then pass the pointer to your `RGBA` instance which then deletes the array in its destructor. As it was not dynamically allocated in the first place, this is a bad thing.

Deleting the array in the destructor indicates that you mean to transfer *ownership* of the array to that class. To do that, you need to either pass a dynamically allocated array or allocate a new array in the constructor and copy the contents of the one passed by parameter.

If you do not need ownership, simply remove the delete call in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
~RGBA() {
    cout << "Destroying object" << endl;
    delete[] _arr;
}
```

Here was your problem because delete didn't work on static array, It always work for dynamic array. `delete` only work for `new`

```
int *arr = new int[3];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
```

this will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you aren't supposed to delete the array.

The implementation of your destructor is correct, but the array is not allocated with `new[]`, so you must not de-allocating with `delete[]`.

If you'd replace your array in your main with it's modernized cousin, `std::array`, and the pointer in your class by `std::vector`, you would see that assigning a array to a vector would require an allocation on the heap and a copy of each element in your array.

A quick way to fix the code would be to allocate the array using `new[]`:

```
int* arr = new int[3]{1, 2, 3};
RGBA rgba(arr, 3);
rgba.print();
```

Now that the array is allocated using `new[]`, it can be safely deleted using `delete[]`.

---

However, please note that in most modern code, you either use `std::array<T, N>`, `std::vector<T>` or `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` to manage arrays.

The resulting code that use arrays and vectors would be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

struct RGBA {
    std::uint8_t red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0, alpha = 255;
    std::vector<int> arr;

    RGBA(std::vector<int> _arr) : arr{std::move(_arr)} {}

    // No destructor needed. vector manages it's own resources.

    void print() {
        for (auto&& number : arr) {
            std::cout << number << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << static_cast<int>(red) << " "
                  << static_cast<int>(blue) << " "
                  << static_cast<int>(green) << " "
                  << static_cast<int>(alpha) << std::endl; 
    }
};

int main() {
    // Create a constant array on the stack the modern way
    constexpr std::array<int, 3> arr{1, 2, 3};

    // Copy array elements in the vector
    RGBA rgba{std::vector<int>{arr.begin(), arr.end()}};

    rgba.print();

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: I think he was trying to play with destructor, and you do not have any destructor in your code.

Comment: @MohammadTayyab you are right. I skipped the part where OP shared it's intentions with its code.

Comment: Ok! I know that, But I thought OP want to know about destructor. That's why I mentioned!

Comment: @MohammadTayyab I edited my answer, it should be better now.